# What is the key point or " nervus probandi" of the proof of Godel-Henkin's Completeness of Predicate Logic? (Attempted outline).

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, metalogic

Context in Crossley's book : PC, a predicate calculus consisting in

- " a denumerable set of individual variables"
- one predicate : $P(x,y) $
- a quantifier : $\exists$
- two connectives : $\land$ , $\neg$
- formation rules
- truth conditions
- axioms
- one inference rule : modus ponens.

---

- I'm currently trying to capture the main features of the proof of predicate logic's completeness, more precsely of the $\Leftarrow$ part, namely : $\vDash \phi \space\implies\space \vdash\phi$
- To show this, it is suffcient ( maybe also necessary) to prove the "Godel-Henkin Completeness Theorem", which reads like this : if $\Sigma$ is a consistent set of formulas, then $\Sigma$ has a model ( that is, there exists an interpretation $\mathcal {A}$ such that every formula $\phi$ belonging to $\Sigma$ is true in $\mathcal {A})$.
- As I understand the proof of Godel-Henkin's Completeness Theorem  ( as it is presented by ***Crossley*** et alii. , in a little volume called  ***What is mathematical logic?*** Chapter1,  OUP 1972) the reasoning goes as follows :

(1) $\Sigma$ is a consistent theory / set of formulas in PC, a Predicate Logic system.

(2) By Lindenbaum's Lemma, we are garanteed that there is at least one full extension of $\Sigma$

(3) In case we find such a full extension that has a model, then  $\Sigma$ has a model , and the proof is completed.

***(4) So, the whole thing is to define and build a set of formulas that $(a)$ is a full extension of $\Sigma$ and $(b)$ that has a model.***

(5) This full extension that has a model , denoted by $\Sigma^{\star}$ ( by Crossley)  , can be built by adding new variables to the $PL$ language and by definig a model $<U, R>$ for $\Sigma^{\star}$ such that the universe $U$ ( of the model) is the set of new variables $b_1, b_2, b_3$ ... and such that $P$ is a binary relation holding between $b_i$ and $b_j$ iff $\Sigma^{\star} \vdash P(i,j)$

***Is this outline correct? I mean, is (4) really the key point of the proof?***

Another way to put my question is : ***the desired result does not follow directly from Lindenbaum's lemma, but why exactly?***

Another question would be : how does the ( complicated) construction of $\Sigma^{\star}$ ensure us that this full extension meets the desired condition of having a model? But this may be too much for a single post.

Comment: "Godel-Henkin's proof" is a non-sequitur: Godel's proof was totally different from Henkin's proof.

Comment: @Noah Schweber. - Thanks for this point. The post is edited. .

Comment: To answer your clarified question, it does not follow directly from Lindenbaum's lemma simply because Lindenbaum's lemma does not produce a model and on its face says nothing about models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't quite outline the proof that way. There are really two new ideas: the main one is that of **term structures**, and the secondary one is the **witness property** (which is how we apply the term structure idea). The whole "Lindenbaum+" machinery is the boring predictable part, and should only be brought into the picture once those key ideas are understood.

---

The first key idea is that of **term structures**. Specifically, given a theory $T$ in a language $L$, there's a natural way to try to build a model of $T$ - namely, look at the set $Term_T$ of (closed) terms of $T$ modulo $T$-provable equality and interpret $L$ over that set in the obvious way:

- We set $f^{Term_T}([t_1],...,[t_n])=[s]$ iff $T\vdash f(t_1,...,t_n)=s$.
- We set $R^{Term_T}=\{([t_1],...,[t_n]): T\vdash R(t_1,...,t_n)\}$.

For example, taking $T=PA$ we have terms like $(1+0)$, $(1+(1\cdot 1))$, $(1+1)+(1+1)$, etc., and $T$ proves all the relevant equalities. So $Term_{PA}\models PA$.

However, in general $Term_T$ is not a model of $T$: even ignoring the situation where there are no closed $L$-terms in the first place (which is somehow the "boring" obstacle), consider the case where $L$ consists of a single constant symbol $c$ and a unary relation $U$ and $T=\{\exists xU(x)\}$. Then $Term_T$ has a single element, namely *(the one-element equivalence class of)* the term $c$, but since $T\not\vdash U(c)$ we have $Term_T\not\models U(c)$ and so $U^{Term_T}=\emptyset$.

---

So this reduces the problem to the following question:

> When does $Term_S\models S$?

The goal of course is to prove "Every $T$ can be 'embedded' in some $S$ such that $Term_S\models S$" (since then the reduct of $Term_S$ to the language of $T$ should be a model of $T$). This takes us to our second key idea: **the witness property**. A theory $S$ has the witness property iff whenever $S\vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$ there is some closed term $t$ such that $S\vdash\varphi(t)$. You can think of this as a cousin of completeness: a complete theory leaves no disjunction unclarified ($T$ is complete iff whenever $T\vdash \varphi\vee\psi$ we have $T\vdash\varphi$ or $T\vdash\psi$), and a theory with the witness property leaves no existential claim unclarified (if $T$ has the witness property then $T$ never tells us something exists without giving us an explicit "named" example).

---

At this point the rest of the proof is basically mechanical:

- Prove that if $T$ is a consistent $L$-theory then there is a language $L'\supseteq L$ and a complete consistent $L'$-theory $T'$ such that $T\subseteq T'$ and $T'$ has the witness property. *(This is an elaboration on Lindenbaum's lemma; note that LL doesn't give you the witness property.)*
- Prove that if $S$ is a complete consistent theory with the witness property, then $Term_S\models S$. *(This is a straightforward induction on formula complexity.)*